# Checkbox en Scriptcase

Tags: php

Mi porblema es que en tengo un checkbox en Sriptcase, necesito que cuando elija una opción de un select, una de las opciones del checkbox desaparezcan. Lo he intentado pero no se me ocurre nada. Algún consejo??

Gracias!

Comment: Podrias [edit] la pregunta y mostrar el codigo con el que estas intentando para entender mejor la pregunta

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo el código.

Comment: A ver En Scriptcase he puesto un checkbox con NOMINA y VACACIONES. Un select con: VACACIONES o DIAS EXTRAS.

Comment: Lo que quiero que haga el programa es que cuando en el select seleccione DIAS EXTRAS, desaparezca VACACIONES del checkbox

Comment: Sin código, la pregunta es muy amplia y la gente va a estar adivinando en las posibles respuestas.